# angular material - mat-error not displaying the error message for the input field

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

Scenario - Reactive form with a form array. Each field in the form has a validation of Required. The form array itself has a validation of minlength(1) and maxlength(3). Adding 4 values in the form array should invalidate the form and display error message - `Maximum 3 values can be added` in the last values field.

Code is on - [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gv8clu)

Issue - even when is condition in *ngIf of mat-error is true, it is not displaying the error for the field (even when the field is touched).

Steps to reproduce -

1. open stackblitz
2. enter 1 in the Value field and click + button
3. enter 2 in the new Value field and click + button
4. enter 3 in the new Value field and click + button
5. enter 4 in the new Value field. Expectation is to show the error `Maximum 3 values can be added` against the last value field.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom validator for your `FormArray`. See an example here.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qx5ttm

Comment: i dont think a custom validator is needed here. Because Validators.maxLength() can be added to form array. And I see that it is working fine because the ngIf condition is changing to true, but issue here is that even if it is true, mat-error is not getting displayed.

Comment: The error is not displaying because the control is in `pristine (untouched)` state. If you change the value and remove it again, you will get both errors. One for required and another for maxLength of Array.

Comment: its not because of the pristine state. Because if I enter a value in the 4th field, then the Required field validation is met, but the maxLength validation fails, so it should still show the maxLength error message. This is not happening currently

Comment: Excerpt from material.angular.io docs `Error messages can be shown under the form field underline by adding mat-error elements inside the form field. Errors are hidden initially and will be displayed on invalid form fields after the user has interacted with the element or the parent form has been submitted. ` Link for reference: https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview. So, the error is displayed only if the input field has an error. In your case, the field only has validation for `required`. SO it wont display the error relating to `FormArray`.

Comment: So basically angular material does not allow me to attach error messages to the input field unless the field is invalid. So what I am trying to achieve is not possible. In this scenario I will have to display the error message separately and cannot club with any of the input fields (because the validation is on the form array and not form control)

Comment: Yes. It seems correct also since your error is on the FormArray, you should not bind it to a specific control.